# Numpy to solve arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Using numpy.linalg.solve to solve a linear algebra equation, but receiving _assertNdSquareness and last 2 dimensions of the array must be square errors:

Any help is appreciated here's my code:

```
c = array([[1, 1, 1], [.07, .08, .09]])
d = array([24000, 1870])
z = linalg.solve(c, d)
print(z)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `numpy.linalg.solve` for non-square matrices as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html#numpy.linalg.solve), `a must be square and of full-rank, i.e., all rows (or, equivalently, columns) must be linearly independent`. Your matrix is not square, but the documentation also mentions this, `if either is not true, use lstsq for the least-squares best “solution” of the system/equation.`

An example of this is below, and should work for you;

```
c = array([[1, 1, 1], [.07, .08, .09]])
d = array([24000, 1870])
z = linalg.lstsq(c, d)[0]
print(z)

# compare d and c*z to be sure
print(numpy.allclose(d,numpy.dot(c,z))) # should be true
```